# Any ideas on which is better? MS One Care or Spyware Doctor?

Tags: anti-virus, malware, spyware, anti-spyware

Does anyone know if the new [Microsoft Malware solution](http://onecare.live.com/standard/en-us/activation/oc_eol_guidance.htm) is better or worse than Spyware Doctor?  My gut tells me that Spyware Doctor would be better just because they aren't a jack-of-all-trades like Microsoft is, but Microsoft's knowledge of their own operating system might give them an advantage as well.

This is a rather subjective question, so I'm going to  mark this as community wiki.

Comment: Just because something does lots of other things, It does not mean it is bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows live one care is EOL, [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/Security_Essentials/) is the new product and I personally love it.

I think it is a very good anti virus solution that will serve you well.

Never heard of Spyware Doctor, and just because Microsoft may be a "jack-of-all-trades" doesn't mean they can't release good products.

[Link to Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/Security_Essentials/)

Comment: And in this case, MSE is a very good product.

Comment: MSE is at the point it is hanging with or even out scoring most other AVG solutions, paid or not.

Answer (score 0):

[AntiVir](http://www.avira.com/en/pages/index.php) or [AVG](http://www.avg.com/de-en/homepage)

Answer (score 0):

With AntiVirus products is often benefitial to use one that used by the least amount of people as possible as it reduces the chances that the maleware is written and tested to circumvent your AntiVirus solution.

Comment: Man that doesn't sound right.